# How Get position for imputbox (VBA) in web page

Tags: javascript, vba, web-scraping

Good afternoon people,
I am creating a vba code to fill some data on the web page, however there is a screen where the user is asked to complete the CPF number, until all is well.
The challenge here is that there are times when the site asks to complete the cpf to the Right:
[image]

and other times the Left:
[image]

What verification (code) can I use to identify the position of the imputbox on the screen and from there to fill in the start (stop) or the end (right) of the cpf?

Comment: Is the HTML for the 2nd image correct?

Comment: Is there an URL please or more HTML as an insert not a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shared any code so no idea how you are trying to go about it.

Once you have the page in question set in an HTML document have you tried

```
htmldoc.getElementById("validador").innerText = "...."
```